# How to check if a slug exists?

Tags: slug

I have a arbitrary string and want to check if a post with that slug string exists in the site. I tried to find a way to list all slugs, but can't find such a thing. Thanks

Comment: The question is protected, so i can't reply. You can use `if(is_page('slug-here')) { echo 'exists'; }`.

Answer (score 10):

This is what you're looking for, tested and I use it on my own sites:

```
function the_slug_exists($post_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
if (the_slug_exists('contact')) {
    // do something
}
```

Replace `contact` with whatever slug you want to test for.

Comment: should we use $wpdb_prepare to prepare escape the SQL statement?

Comment: Any chance to modify the code to only target a specific custom post type?

Comment: Maybe `if(the_slug_exists('contact') && post_type_exists('contact'))` but then why not only use `if(post_type_exists('contact')) ...`

Comment: Using WP_Query() is a more maintainable solution than a direct DB query. For example, `$query = new WP_Query(array('name' => 'my-new-slug')); if ($query->post_count == 0) {// I am unique!}`

Comment: Also, the database prefix is not guaranteed to be `wp_`

Comment: It can be written like this to use the correct prefix:`("SELECT post_name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_name = '$post_name'", 'ARRAY_A'))`

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean post slug? You can try to make use of [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) that WP uses to generate those. If I remember right if slug you are trying to use is not unique it will be returned with numerical index appended.

Comment: sorry to reply so late. Yes post slug is the slug I want. Unfortunately I don't have the post_id which is required to use `wp_unique_post_slug()`

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use wp_unique_post_slug to do this anyway. It does really check to see if a slug exists, as much as create one. I could be wrong or misinterpreting something but in my testing it would not check if something already existed.

Answer (score 5):

How about this simpler approach?

```
$post_exists = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, $post_type );
if ( ! $post_exists )
    echo 'No post exists with this slug.';
```

If a post doesn't exist for the given slug and post type provided then [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/) returns null.

Comment: Note that path is not quite the same thing as a slug (or `post_name` to use the name of the database column). If a post has a parent post, then its path will be `parent_slug/slug`

Answer (score 4):

```
$args = array('name' => $slugName, 'post_type' => $postType); 

$slug_query = new WP_Query($args);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($slug_query);
exit;
```

You then have more than enough information to test if a post was returned or not, hope this helps.

Comment: How this will extract slug uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_slug = 'my-pageeeeeee';
$wpdb = $GLOBALS['wpdb'];



//==================FIRST method======================
    $id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_name = '%s' AND ( post_type = 'page' OR post_type = 'post') ", $slug) );
    if (!empty($id)) {
        //............
    }





//====================SECOND method======================
    $counts = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count(post_name) FROM ".$wpdb->posts ." WHERE post_name like '%s'", $slug) );
    if ($counts >=1 ) {
        //.............
    }
```

Comment: Please add proper explanation to your answers like what the code does and how it should be used